# How to alter the data returned by $resource in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an API that returns JSON data in this format:

```
{
    paging: {
        previous: null,
        next: null
},
    data: [
        { title: 'First Item' },
        { title: 'Second Item' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm using Angular's [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) service to fetch this data.
My code - which is located in a controller - goes something like this:

```
var Entity = $resource('/api/entities');
var entities = $scope.entities = Entity.get();
```

And then, in the view, I can display the data like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="entity in entities.data">{{entity.title}}</<li>
</ul>
```

It all works fine, but:

- I'd rather expose only the contents of `entities.data` to the view, instead of the whole `entities` object. How can I intercept the data returned by the GET request to modify it **before** it populates `$scope.entities`?
- Correlated question: since I am fetching an **array** of data, it would be cleaner to use `Entity.query()` instead of `Entity.get()`. But if I use `Entity.query()` in the code above, I get an error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'". This makes sense, since the API is returning an object instead of an array (hence, no 'push' method on the object). Again, if I could extract the `.data` attribute from the response, I'd have an array.

Following [these indications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835877/1153681) by Dan Boyon, I managed to customize the default `$resource` service and to override the .get() or .query() methods, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: out of curiosity (even though this is old), why didn't your API return the paging data in the headers?

Comment: @EddieMongeJr: No idea, Eddie. I can't even remember which API it was but the thing is I had no control over it.

Comment: Take a look at the 'transformResponse' option in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think you need to modify the get or query defaults.  Just use the success callback to do what you want.  It should be more robust as well.

```
Entity.get(
    {}, //params
    function (data) {   //success
        $scope.entities = data.data;
    },
    function (data) {   //failure
        //error handling goes here
    });
```

Html will be cleaner, too:

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="entity in entities">{{entity.title}}</<li>
 </ul>
```

By the way, I usually declare services for my resources and then inject them into my controllers as I need them.

```
 myServices.factory('Entity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('/api/entities', {}, {
     });
 }]);
```

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks, that works perfectly. I was aware of the success and failure callbacks, but it didn't occur to me to do the scope assignment there.

Comment: Trying this same method, I'm getting an error saying "TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'". The documentation for $resource is really bad. Their examples look totally different from yours and neither is working.

Comment: @blesh that error usually occurs when you're receiving back an array into $resource when isArray: false, such as using get.  If you're receiving an array you probably want to use query which defaults isArray: true.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Now however, the array of strings I'm getting back from my service actually comes back as an array of arrays.  So rather than it being: ["one", "two"] it's [['o','n','e'],['t','w','o']]  ... very strange.

Comment: ... apparently my issue mentioned in the above comment has to do with me returning an array of strings and not objects. Which makes sense given how $resource adds methods to the results it gets.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/QjhN9-UeBVM/UjSgc5CNDqMJ%5B1-25%5D

Comment: this solution works fine for query, but you can no longer call data.$save() to get the restful behavior of the $resource service. I'm still looking for a workaround to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Response Transformer (transformResponse) like this:

```
$resource('/api/entities', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'json',
            isArray: true,
            transformResponse: function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }
        }
    });
```

This code modifies the "query" method behaviour, you can do the same for "get" ... !

Comment: Fantastic! Mind the "responseType" mentioned above - otherwise you'll get a String.