# Angularjs getting value of response using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the response of a request using `$resource`, for example I have:

```
angular.module('app').factory('AuthResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        isAuthenticated : function() {
            return $resource('/api/v1/auth/authenticated').query();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then in my controller I'm calling this service and doing:

```
console.log(AuthResource.isAuthenticated());
```

This doesn't return the actual result, which is simply a single object `{'success' : 'true'}`.

Instead it returns:

```
Resource {$resolved: false, $then: function, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
$resolved: true
$then: function (callback, errback) {
success: false
__proto__: Resource
```

How do I go about getting the actual returned object? I'm not applying this to any models, just using the data to determine some routing.

Thank you!

Comment: check out [this answer][1] , it helped me out


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16197255/1505895

Answer (score 3):

I set up a test like this:

```
var status = {};
$httpBackend.expectGET("/api/Accounts/AuthenticationStatus").respond(status);
```

Then I had an expectation:

```
expect(actual).toBe(status);
```

I was getting the following error:

```
Expected { $resolved : true, $then : Function } to be { }.
```

After scratching my head for a long time, I finally realized that the object returned by the get() function was never going to be exactly the same object I set up the $httpBackend service to respond with, but that it would return the base object { $resolved : ..., $then : ... } and, when resolved, add the additional fields included with my response object to that object.

Hope that makes better sense than the previous poster.

Answer (score 2):

Just Modify you code as below

```
angular.module('app').factory('AuthResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        isAuthenticated : function() {
            return $resource('/api/v1/auth/authenticated')
        }
    }
}]);

--controller 
AuthResource.isAuthenticated().query(function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

When the data is returned from the server then the object is an instance of the resource type and all of the non-GET methods are available with $ prefix

Comment: This still returns `[Resource, $resolved: true, $then: function]`

Comment: When the data is returned from the server then the object is an instance of the resource type and all of the non-GET methods are available with $ prefix

Answer (score 0):

Can you base a solution on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856710/1371408. Something like:

```
AuthResource.isAuthenticated(
    {}, // params (ie. none)
    function (data) { // success callback
        // do what you want with values returned from successful request, contained in 'data'
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error); // Error details
    }
);
```